# The specified command ("storybook") is invalid. For a list of available options (angular cli 13)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-storybook

im my `angular 13.1.1` application i added storybook and manually adding `angular cli` build option to the project so that it will use angular build to build storybook be getting invalid option error

**Below is the storybook config in `angular.json`**

```
        "storybook": {
          "builder": "@storybook/angular:start-storybook",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "website:build",
            "styles": [".storybook/custom-styles.scss"]
          }
        },
```

The error I am getting after running `ng storybook` is as below

> The specified command ("storybook") is invalid. For a list of available options

Comment: `ng storybook`? Maybe try `npm run storybook`.

Comment: @R.Richards, i added the angular cli config. the normal one will directly call the script tag in my package.json